# How to setup PhpStorm to start a "watch" task when its project is opened?

Tags: phpstorm

I have a gruntfile.js in my project and the file contains a watch task that watches changes in JS and CSS files. How can I avoid manually starting this task via Grunt Console in PhpStorm?

(I often forgot to run the task and I'm often surprised why my changes are not reflected in website's behaviour. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not possible at the moment.
>
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11818 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

**UPDATE:** It has been implemented as of PhpStorm 2016.1 version.

You can now select any existing Run Configuration to be executed on project opening. Grunt/Gulp/NPM Script are supported.

[Official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/startup-tasks.html?search=startup)